# Download file > 5 GB from Server ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, download

I use this example but it just can download file < 4 GB. How to increase up to > 5 GB. Help me

Example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-implement-resume-in-84f5bc1c

The problem is that I can not download files larger than 5 GB. Do you understand ? I received a message: The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

I have been successful with files that are under 4 GB or 4 GB. But can not download files larger than 5 GB

Answer (score 1):

Please read your own link. It is a tutorial in itself, with code samples, etc.

> - C# code snippet
>
>   ```
>   public class DownloadHttpHandler : IHttpHandler  { 
>
>       public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>       { 
>           string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"]; 
>           Downloader.DownloadFile(context, filePath); 
>       } 
>       public bool IsReusable 
>       { 
>           get { return false; } 
>       }
>   ```

They also tell you more on the website you linked to.

Comment: I know that. The problem is that I can not download files larger than 5 GB. Do you understand ?

I received a message: The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.

Comment: I have been successful with files that are under 4 GB or 4 GB. But can not download files larger than 5 GB

Comment: @HuyHaHuy The information should be [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49217670/5267751)ed into the question instead of being added as a comment.